# what is the benefits of using lightning/uiRecordApi instead of @wire

Tags: lightning-web-components

Let's say we need to obtain one field based on Account Object. We can use @wire with apex controller (or imperative call as well) but will it be better to use lightning/uiRecordApi approach?

Comment: We don't need to maintain any Apex code, test coverage and other than that, we don't need to worry about record access field access etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to reduced server side code, lightning/ui*Api leverages Lightning Data Service, so will enforce CRUD and FLS rules and bring about other benefits that can be read here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_ui_api

Lightning modules like ui*Api should be used for simple use cases to reduce the amount of code to maintain and to avoid accidents such as exposing fields that a user should not be able to see by not explicitly restricting it in your code.

Comment: Two really key parts of this worth explicitly mentioning: 1. caching for performance and 2. sharing of that cache across all components that reference a specific record (e.g. the record page's contextual record) meaning that all components in the page using the same data will be correctly refreshed together without writing any extra code to make it happen.